# adjusting position of page numbers in bound in PDF pages

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

My document consists of three parts, where part two is an external PDF which I bound in using the `\includepdf` command from the `pdfpages` package. I managed to place page numbers on these pages by use of the option `pagecommand={}`; e.g. `\includepdf[pages=2,noautoscale,pagecommand={}]{Part_2.pdf}`.

There is, however, one subtle thing I'd like to have adjusted: As it is now, all page numbers are displayed in the respective top outer corner. However I would like to have the page number of the first page of the PDF to be displayed in the middle at the bottom.

How can I do that? (The document class used is `amsbook`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the first page with the `pagecommand` --  `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` and rest of the pages with `pagecommand={}`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{duck1.pdf} %% first page - put pages=1
\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale,pagecommand={}]{duck2.pdf} %% second page put pages=2-2 instead of pages=-
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Picture courtesy by @Paulo Cereda (Thanks Paulo -- more ducks!)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! (and for the fancy illustrative example) ;)